# Titanium and Android: Using button inside textfield

Tags: android, mobile, titanium

Is it possible to make a textfield with buttons inside? I found the properties rightButton and leftButton, but using Android (emulator) does not work. Is there another alternative?

That is the used code:

```
var rightButton1 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    color:'#fff',
    width:25,
    height:25,
    right:10,
    backgroundImage:'plus.png',
    backgroundSelectedImage:'plus.png',
    backgroundDisabledImage: 'plus.png'
});

rightButton1.addEventListener('click',function()
{
    Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
        title:'Button clicked',
        message:'Button clicked'
    }).show();
});

var textField3 = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    color:'#336699',
    width:"auto",
    height:"auto",
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    rightButton:rightButton1
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post all your relevant code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [KitchenSink](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/textfield.js) it's an iPhone only function currently.

```
if(Titanium.Platform.name == 'iPhone OS') {
    data.push({title:'Buttons on Textfields', hasChild:true, test:'../examples/textfield_buttons.js'});
}
```

However I don't see why you couldn't fake this by creating a `view` and placing the button on top of the `textField` because `Titanium.UI.Android` supports `zIndex` just fine and the `focus` event to toggle the visibility of the `button`.

```
var view = Ti.UI.createView();

var textField = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    // cordinates using top, right, left, bottom
    zIndex: 1
});

var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    // cordinates using top, right, left, bottom
    visible: false,
    zIndex: (textField.zIndex + 1)
});

view.add(textField);
Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(button);
Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(view);

// you only need the listeners if you want to hide and show the button
textField.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    button.show();
});

textField.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    button.hide();
});
```